# Water pressure tanks

Tags: plumbing

I want to buy a new pump, were as my current one is 42 yrs old. With the new pump I would like to use my current 19 gallon tank, plus I want to if possible install a new 50 gallon tank tied together. Would the different in tank capacity be a problem??  The current 19 gallon tank is fine not that old, would like to have more draw down in between pump cycles.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem. Pressure tank volumes add in series and this should do exactly what you want.